# H-Bridge not pulling enough power

Tags: transistors

I have an h-bridge I have setup using transistors. The transistors I'm using are TIP120 (NPN) and TIP125 (PNP).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp3oEf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They both are supposed to run at a max of 60V with a 10V max base. I am supplying the circuit with 25V at 4.5A and controlling the gate with a 9V battery. This setup was fine when I using 40V transistors rather than 60V. However, the current setup is only letting through about 0.2V. While with the 40V setup up, I was getting well over 8V using a 12V input supply.

Comment: I hope you didn't actually put BAT2 as shown, without resistors at the base (same for Q1/Q2). The transistors also seem to be all put upside-down. Please show the *real* schematic, especially as your description isn't quite clear (sorry to say so).

Comment: I'm not resisting the 9V because the transistors are made to work with up to 12V. It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to resist when running for long periods of time, but just a few second test should still work I think.

Comment: "made to work with up to 12V"? Show me where you got that. These are not MOSFET. These are BJT transistors. You can't have 9V across base and emitter, even for a short time. But I realized they are probably not broken because they currently *work as emitter-followers*. Which is a really bad idea for a bridge (and explains what you see). But if you put them the right way around, they would blow without resistor. Tell me how you came to set them this way, I'm curious.

Comment: I'm with @dim. There's something wrong with this design. You should add R's in the base. In the following link there's plenty of H_Bridge designs, maybe can help: http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/H-Bridge/H-Bridge-1.html

Comment: There is a special hell for those who draw schemes where current flows upwards.

Comment: @greg actually, positive supply is top and ground bottom, it's the transistors that are the wrong way (C and E the other way around).

Comment: Yes, but the NPN in the bottom is inverse...

Comment: By the way, drawing everything in one certain direction helps avoiding those mistakes, even if you are an expert. For instance, you need a very good reason to draw NPN this way, and you usually don't have it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the schematic is clearly none-sense and the OP is showing no signs of fixing it and indeed appears to be resisting this.

Comment: 10V forward bias on the base-emitter junction will destroy any bipolar transistor instantly. What are you REALLY trying to do here? Possibly @WhatRoughBeast's answer may be the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty clear that what you're trying to do is something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZqTjt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where you apply 9 volts to one NPN or the other, depending on the direction you want. For the resistor values shown you'll get base currents of about 14 mA, which should give you a decently-saturated output for 3 amps of motor current. If you really expect 4.5 amps, I suggest you halve the resistor values. Motor voltage should be around 20 to 21 volts, assuming your 9 volt battery is up the task of providing a real 9 volts at the current levels indicated.

Please note that you need to do some research on "flyback diodes". Your schematic doesn't have them, and you are at some risk of destroying your transistors.